# The given path's format is not supported using File.ReadAllText

Tags: c#, .net, xml, wpf

I have a WPF application. I am loading some data from XML file.

I receive an error:

```
System.NotSupportedException was unhandled
Message: The given path's format is not supported.
```

on this line:

```
string html = File.ReadAllText(Advertisement.DescriptionUrl);
```

the url in the xml it is:

```
http://mysitetest.com/x/x/Assets/shop/shopdetails/Coffee/image.png
```

Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: please guys add a comment when down-voting thanks

Comment: If we let the fact that File.ReadAllText does not handle url's, `image.png` is hardly going to be a text file, so reading it as text will likely not be what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`File.ReadAllText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalltext.aspx) is meant to take a *filename* on a file system - not a URL.

You'll need to fetch it with something like [`WebClient.DownloadString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadstring.aspx):

```
string text;
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    text = client.DownloadString(url);
}
// Now use text
```

Answer (score 1):

That's a web URL, not a file path.

Use a `WebClient` object to request the resource:

```
string html;
using (WebClient client = new WebClient()) {
  html = client.DownloadString(Advertisement.DescriptionUrl);
}
```